# How to store Blob in CouchDB using Java?

Tags: java, couchdb, blob, storing-data

I have a blob and want to store it to the Apache CouchDb in java. I get the blob like this

```
Blob blob1 = blobStore.getBlob(containerName, fileName);
```

How do I store it in CouchDB?

Comment: CouchDB allows you to store files as attachments to documents in a database. What CouchDB Java API are you using? What is the Blob class here?

Comment: hii thanks sir. org.jclouds.blobstore.domain.Blob this is the type of blob and I am using org.ektorp .I am new to couchDB . please help me if you have any code snippet or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a set up to test this out, but looking at the documentation, you want to do something like this:

```
...
Blob blob = blobStore.getBlob(containerName, fileName);
InputStream is = blob.getPayload.openStream();
String contentType = "image/jpeg"; //or whatever content the blob is.
AttachmentInputStream ais = new AttachmentInputStream("attachment_id", is, contentType);
db.createAttachment("new_document_id", ais);
...
```

Obviously you would need exception handling and error checking.

Comment: If this has helped you cold you please up vote and accept my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Ha, yes :).  Though I think you should be able to accept the answer with any rep. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419). You also get a little rep for doing so.